# Emberjs call a method from an other object

Tags: ember.js

This might be a silly question, but I can't find out anything about it anywhere...

I create a method in one of my controller to verify if the user session is still good, and I'm using this method in almost every page of my app in my beforeModel. But the thing is that I don't want to copy/paste the code every time in every route, this will be dirty and I really don't like it.

Lets say I have this controller :

```
App.LoginController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
   ...
    isSession: function() {
        var session = this;
        Ember.$
        .get(host + '/session', function(data) {
            console.log('DEBUG: Session OK');
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log('DEBUG: Session FAIL');
            session.transitionToRoute('login');
        });
    }
});
```

How can I call it in this router :

```
App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    beforeModel: function(transition) {
      //Here
    },
    model: function() {
        return this.store.all('login');
    }
});
```

I've tried this `this.get('loginController').isSession();` but I receive this error `Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot call method 'isSession' of undefined`

Thanks for the help !

[edit]

I don't have much to show but this :

My map

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.route('login', { path: '/' });
    this.route('home');
    this.resource('enquiries', function() {
       this.route('enquiry', { path: '/:enquiry_id' }, function() {
           this.route('update');
       });
    });
});
```

Most likely I only Have a LoginController and my HomeRoute. (its the beginning of the app)
I don't need to create a Route for my Login because I have an action helper in my login template and I'm redirected to my Home template after that.

Comment: so, you want to access your loginController from that route ?, try with this.controllerFor('loginController')

Comment: Just tried but I've got some other error too : 

`Assertion failed: The controller named 'loginController' could not be found. Make sure that this route exists and has already been entered at least once. If you are accessing a controller not associated with a route, make sure the controller class is explicitly defined.` And 
`Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot call method 'isSession' of undefined`

Comment: ok, then that's the problem, isn't it loaded yet ? does it belong to a route ?, because the code I gave you is the way to access controllers in routes. Something else is happening, and I don't know what it is because I don't know the architecture of your app.

Comment: Just edited the main post, do you need to see something else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `controllerFor()` method in order to call method on controller from router. If method is an action you need to use `send()` method, like `this.controllerFor('login').send('isSession')`

```
App.HomeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  actions: {
    willTransition: function(transition) {
      transition.abort();
      this.controllerFor('login').isSession()
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks man, this works perfectly ;) but is it dirty to dev an ember app this way ? such as calling method from another controller ?

Comment: @SuperMarco I've added one improvement to the answer in case if `isSession()` take too long to execute. About your question in comment I think this is wrong approach: `this.controllerFor('login').session = true` but not `this.controllerFor('login').isSession()` or `this.controllerFor('login').send('isSession')`. As long you are using methods to do something is fine, when you trying to set directly value on another controller like `this.controllerFor('login').session = true` is as you call it dirty.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need a return value from `isSession` you might consider making it an `action` on a top-level route. [The router.send method in the docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_send) has a pretty good example of how you declare actions as well as how you call them. Note that `send` is also a method you can call on a controller. Actions bubble up from a controller, to the parent route, and then all the way up the route hierarchy, as shown [here](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/#toc_action-bubbling)

Comment: That's interesting! I've put my method in an actions handler in HomeRoute and its working fine for other Route. But not for the HomeRoute ? Is there is any higher level route ? like indexRoute ?

Comment: Yup. `ApplicationRoute`